# What kind of spider is this please?

Tags: species-identification

[image]

What type of spider is this PLEASE. My friend found it in her home. She has 3 boys under 10yrs old and people are telling her its a wolf spider i really dont think it is. Please help

Comment: It looks similar to a fishing spider. Please let us know your locale so we can make a more accurate determination.

Comment: We need to know the region, and also the size of this spider.

Comment: If you are in the US there are very few spiders that bite unprovoked. It looks more like a wolf than a brown recluse. (one of the few possibly dangerous US spiders, still needs to be provoked)

Comment: https://entomology.ca.uky.edu/ef631 can you get a better photo of the eyes please?

Comment: but they look like non recluse eyes to me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a Wolf spider to me, probably one of the [Tigrosa](https://bugguide.net/node/view/747000) (formerly Hogna and Allocosa) species.  The narrow central line on the 'head', and what appears to be a blocky dark central mark at the front of the abdomen, are what I would expect.  I can't tell if the appearance of bands on the legs is real or an artifact of the light and photograph.  Oh, yes - these spiders are quite harmless (to humans, anyway), like almost all spiders.  They can give you a bite if you force them to, but I've handled them a lot and have never been bitten.  I would expect it to hurt a bit like a wasp sting, though.

[image]